# India immigration law: Does religious freedom provide an excuse to overstay a visa?

Tags: india, immigration, visa

If a person overstays their tourist visa in India while staying with a guru in an ashram, can they be excused without penalty when they exit?

Comment: I'm not well versed on Indian law, but in general, most immigration limit violation excuses have to be either out of one's control (e.g. one's flight is cancelled or delayed) or is due to danger to oneself or other legal restrictions preventing one from carrying out one's promised obligation to leave by the specified date (e.g. war has broken out in you home country, so you cannot safely return; COVID quarantine measures; etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a fee for an exit visa, but not necessarily a penalty per se. However, if your overstay is over 1 year, that's a more severe issue. [Here](https://indiaevisas.org/how-to-get-exit-permit-in-india/) is the procedure, assuming a 30 day tourist visa, which is not renewable. In applying tor an exit visa, you have to explain why you overstayed your visa, so you can fill in a religious explanation (in fact there is a second line for "In case of Missionary explain nature of work"). In case of extreme overstay, FRRO/FRO may assess an penalty as opposed to a processing fee.